# Python: Elegant way to return multiple values in a while loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm pretty much just doing this...

```
while not something():
    pass
```

But I want the function something() to return another value other than True or False, specifically a list. In C I'd just return it by plugging in a reference as a parameter but Python doesn't seem to like doing things that way. Therefore in the something() function I would obviously just return 2 values. I'm ok with that. The issue I have is that the code with the while loop doesn't look elegant and so I presume there must be a better way.

In C:

```
int a[2];
while(!something(a)); //presume that 'a' updates and the loop breaks
```

In Python:

```
bool_value, a = something()
while not bool_value:
    bool_value, a = something()
```

I know it's not such a big deal but just the fact that I have to write the same line twice seems a bit bad. Is there some sort of syntax I can use to call the function and return the 'a' all within the while line?

Comment: From your code it seems like `a` is ignored unless `bool_value` is True, is that accurate?

Comment: Yeah it will return true when it's able to get a value for 'a'. I could just have it return None for 'a' and loop over that as a single return, but I'm just interested in finding the best way while returning multiple variables.

Answer (score 3):

```
while True:
    bool_value, a = something()
    if not bool_value:
       break
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

The answer by user2393267 is the idiomatic way of doing `do..while` kind of structure in Python. You can, however, follow exactly the same pattern as you have in your question for the list case:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
while not something(a):
    pass
```

It's just not very Pythonic, but it will actually work and allow you to modify `a`.

Comment: Well I tried that initially but the 'a' list wasn't modified at all and so I presumed that it wouldn't work in python.

Comment: Note that assignment will create a new list, so if you tried a= in the function it would appear not to work. But you can modify the list in place.